# Remove 1-D from 3-D matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a 3-Dimensional matrix in Matlab (2 x 2 x 56 complex double).
I want to ignore/remove the 1st dimension (2) so the remaining part will be (2x56) and then use it to do some plotting. How can I do that?

I have come through squeeze (which actually removes the singleton) so it doesn't work here. Anything similar to it?

Comment: Remove the dimension? Your matrix has 224 elements, you want to keep 112. Which half do you want? Look for indexing.

Comment: Yes, I want to keep the second half

Comment: Assuming your original matrix is stored in `M` then you want `M_part = squeeze(M(2,:,:));`

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem, can't upvote due to low rep